# correlation between noise and signal is not close to zero in Matlab

Tags: matlab

i am a beginer of Matlab.
i have one question about why the correlation out_cor(m) below are not close to zero? is there anything wrong with my understanding: a random noise signal has no correlation with a determined signal, even if N is very large.
thanks for your hlep.
regards
jeff

```
N=1024*4;
f0=1e3;
fs=64*f0;
n=1:N;x=0.01*randn(1,N);
y=sin(2*pi*f0*n/fs);
figure(1)
plot(n,x,n,y);
out_cor=xcorr(x-mean(x),y);
figure(2)
plot(out_cor);
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of **xcorr** with no scaling options will give you a correlation sequence that isn't normalized by the number of samples.  You can see that if you plot this:

```
xcorr(y, y)
```

Your vector **y** is zero mean, so the maximum value of the auto correlation sequence should equal the variance of **y**.  In this case, you just need to divide your correlation sequence by *N-1* to see the correctly scaled values.

If you want to see how two signals correlate to one other you need a frame of reference.  One way is to compare the cross correlation against the autocorrelation values of each individual signal.  A better way is to measure correlation coefficients which are normalized values of your sequence ranging from -1 to 1.  You can do this with **xcorr** just by passing an additional argument:

```
xcorr(x, y, 'coeff')
```

A coefficient of 1 is a perfect match, -1 is a perfect inverse (correlating **x** with **-x** will get you this), and 0 means the signals are completely uncorrelated.

Comment: Nice answer! Keep on!